# 3D map with latitude and longitude

Tags: 3d

I have a 3D map with latitude and longitude details. Is there a way I can take a 2D image (a png image) from 3D model in such a way that my 2D image also have the latitude and longitude as it is in 3d model ?

Can 2D image have the details as latitude and longitude ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty vague, but it sounds like what you want is a GIS raster image. A GIS *raster* is a grid with a defined geographic location and projection in which the value of each cell represents some quantity.

One use for GIS raster data is to represent [Digital Elevation Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_elevation_model), which describe the elevation at each location in the grid cell.

Desktop GIS software, including the market-leading [ArcGIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcgis) and the open-source [GRASS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASS_GIS) and [qGIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qgis), are able to easily project and overlay different raster files, including formats such as PNG.

Look into these options, and ask over at GIS.stackexchange.com if you have more questions.

Comment: Looking at your old questions, it would be helpful to know what sort of 3d model you're working with. Is it a terrain model? An architectural model? GIS is very accustomed to working with terrain data, but it is possible to work with architectural models in the same way (for example, to model wind or sunlight in an urban area).

Comment: Its a Architectural model. Basically, I want bunch of 2D images which would have the same latitude, longitude as in my 3D model.